# Log viewer for blackberry device like DDMS

Tags: debugging, blackberry, blackberry-10, momentics

I am new to Blackberry device. I need to see device logs for the running apps like DDMS in case of Android while connecting the device through USB. Any solution?

Comment: Are you programming for BlackBerry 7 OS or BlackBerry 10?

Comment: Blackberry z10 running on 10.2. Sorry for not mentioning it.

Comment: But Console is in momentics. So is file explorer. Or do you want something else?

Answer (score 0):

You need momentics and link your device to momentics,then:

On  momentics IDE

Window --> Show perspective -->QNX system information--> click your device -->launch ssh --> then the  Terminal showing ssh

if you want to show all log real time,input:
$ slog2info -w

if you want to the log for certain app real time,input:
$ slog2info -w -s theNameOfYourApp